# Docker swarm, Jenkins, Continuous integration and deployment

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, docker-swarm

I am new to docker swarm and jenkins.

I have a docker swarm cluster which is running in AWS EC2.

```
Cluster has 1 manager and 1 worker node. 
My db container is running in Manager node.
My web container is running in worker node. 
I have Jenkins server running on a separate server in EC2.
I have my source code in Git.
```

Now, whenever I make a change in the source code on local development computer and push it to git, my web container should be updated with the code changes which I pushed into Git.

How to implement this. Kindly let me know.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I just finished all my setup.
I searched in google and came to know jenkins can take care of creating an image and pushing it to image repository,  for that we need to keep the dockerfile in git.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your Jenkins job is set up to fetch source code from the git repository, you have to rebuild the job each  time after `git push`.
Also, you can set up the automatic rebuild if a new commit has been pushed to Git or using a schedule (Poll SCM) in the job's `Build Trigger` section. 
Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks much for your answer. I will try this.